# Cronjob weekly report on fedora core 6

Tags: cron

I need to take weekly report of members using crontab in fedora core 6.

I updated this line in etc/crontab

0 * * * * lynx -dump http://domain.com/weeklyreport.php

then in comand prompt I gave as

crontab crontab

but still not getting report in the mail

If i give 10 then i need to get report every ten minutes.

What is wrong in it? I am not getting report.

All php script written in the weeklyreport.php and it resides in root.

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Well when you add a entry in /etc/crontab you need to tell it which user to run it as. How you have it now its trying to run -dump command by the user lynx. Also it's always a good idea to put the full path in crontab. So if you want to run the command every hour which is how you have it now

```
0 * * * * root /usr/bin/lynx -dump http://domain.com/weeklyreport.php
```

I *think* you want to run it weeklY?

```
0 * * * 0 root /usr/bin/lynx -dump http://domain.com/weeklyreport.php
```

That will run it every Sunday at midnight

Comment: Thank you,

I added the line to get every ten minutes for testing but still not getting the report

10 * * * * root /usr/bin/lynx -dump http://domain.com/weeklyreport.php

What is wrong in the link?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I added the line to get every ten minutes for testing but still not getting the report 10 * * * * root /usr/bin/lynx -dump domain.com/weeklyreport.php What is wrong in the link?

Comment: Can u give the path info of weeklyreport.php